# The content is animated by clicking the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

how to do as on this page http://webredox.net/demo/wp/vking/video/ all content scrolls to the left and reads the new site content sorry for my English

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score -1):

All the properties are used in the above link are css3 transform properties. Mostly scaleX().  Do visit w3schools for more info.